# Is "certified equivalent" proper English?

Tags: grammar

Is "certified equivalent" in the following advertisement proper English? Maybe "equivalence/equivalency certification" is a better choice? Thank you for your help in advance

> "English teaching position needed to be filled immediately! Great bilingual private school. Masters in education (or certified equivalent) needed."

Comment: "Equivalent certification" would be better.

Comment: Thank you for your help !